# ONNX object from PyTorch model without exporting

Tags: pytorch, onnx, pytorch-lightning, onnxruntime, onnx-coreml

Is it possible to convert the PyTorch Model to ONNX without exporting and further use it as an ONNX object directly in the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can export to memory, something like this:

```
import io
f = io.BytesIO()
torch.onnx.export(model, sample_inputs, f, ...)
onnx_model = onnx.load_model_from_string(f.getvalue())
```